# VBA: When copy paste a range as table from Excel to Word (.bookmark) a cell gets separated

Tags: excel, vba

With the code below a range incl. a picture whithin is copy pasted from Excel to a Word bookmark. As a result in the Word table a cell next to the picture gets seperated (see Screenshot). I checked if this has something to do with the picture, and it does. If I remove it and then run the code, the table gets inserted correctly.

What can I do to insert the table together with the picture so that it looks similar as in Excel?

The range how it looks in Excel.
[image: The range how it looks like in Excel.]

The copied range how it looks in Word.
[image: The range how it looks like in Word.]

**Edited -> Solved issue:**
Named the image, placed it in another area, then retrieved it using the code below and pasted it into a specific cell in the Word table.
*[image: Result after using the added code, see comment in code below]*

```
Sub Export2Doc()

    Const stWordDocument As String = "Test_Word.docx"
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wbBook.Path & "\" & stWordDocument)
    
    With wdDoc

        .Bookmarks("Manufacturer").Range = Form.Range("E8").Value
        .Bookmarks("Material").Range = Form.Range("E9").Value

        Form.Range("D25:J62").Copy
        .Bookmarks("Form_1").Range.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        With .Tables(1)
            .Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
            .Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
            .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
            .AllowAutoFit = True
            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Added this code which copies the picture as shape and puts it to a specific cell in the Word table
            Form.Shapes("STRCrown").Copy
            With .Cells(4, 1)
               .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
               .VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
               .Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
            End With
            'End of the added code
            '---------------------
        End With
        
        .TablesOfContents(1).Update

        .SaveAs2 wbBook.Path & "\\MaterialAccess_" & Form.Range("E9") & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmm") & ".docx"

        .ExportAsFixedFormat wbBook.Path & "\MaterialAccess_" & Form.Range("E9") & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmm") & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF
        
        .Save
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    wdApp.Quit
    
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Document created", vbInformation
    
EndRoutine:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest 1. Create a variable for the picture as shape. 2. Set the picture (shape) to variable. 3. Delete the picture, run your code coping the range. 4. Then put the shape in Word to the right place.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSTV! Your suggestion works fine! I solved the issue by using the code I added above.